# What is this Access bug? You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time

Tags: ms-access, locking, ms-access-2003

Tested on Access 2003 Pro (build 11.8321.8324) SP3.

Steps to reproduce:

- create a new database.
- create a new form.
- put a button on the form.
- paste the following code in the button's Click event procedure:

> `Debug.Print Workspaces.Count`
>      `Debug.Print CurrentDb.Name`

- close the code editor and form, saving changes.
- *do not skip this step*: close Access.
- re-open Access and your database.
- open the form
- click the button
- click the toolbar button to switch the form to design mode.

You should see the following error dialog:

> You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. If you proceed to make changes, you may not be able to save them later.

[image: Access error dialog]

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: After closing, is the lock file (.ldb) still there, ie, is not auto deleted?

Comment: @awrigley: No it's deleted OK.

Comment: There must be some issue with counting the workspaces, for some reason it may think that a different project has accessed/opened it.  But I speculate and I haven't a clue really.  I would contact MS.

Comment: @awrigley: "count" is a red herring. From my experiments, you just have to refer to "Workspaces", so I chose an innocuous-looking property.

Comment: Does DBEngine.Workspaces.Count cause the same problem? My guess is that DAO.Workspaces.Count is being used, and that's initializing somehing in DAO that's causing the problem. I've never used the Workspaces collection except as a child of DBEngine. Of course, that maybe doesn't make sense, since DBEngine is itself a child of both DAO and the Application object, so unless DBEngine.Workspaces defaults to the Application parent, it can't be the cause of the problem. You should test it without a reference to DAO.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Even though `DAO.Workspaces Is Access.Application.DBEngine.Workspaces`, that very expression causes the bug. If the arguments to `Is` are swapped however, it doesn't. Also no bug if the DAO 3.6 reference is removed and DAO 3.51 inserted (but then the two Workspaces objects are not the same).

Comment: My suggestion is to try it without any DAO reference, because then there won't be any ambiguity.

Comment: Even though both paths return the same thing, you're doing it through different libraries. One is using the DAO library, and the other is using the Access application, and I'm suggesting that the problem is caused by one or the other different paths (I suspect DAO, actually).

Comment: I'm also getting the TRUE for comparing the return value of both, and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I removed the ambiguity by fully-qualifying the names. The problem does seem to be caused by referring to `DAO.Workspaces` before referring to anything which will trigger a correct initialization. (and I guess the arguments to `Is` are evaluated left first, then right. Not surprisingly.)

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: It sounds like maybe you can't test the actual bug. What versions of Access and DAO do you have?

Comment: I haven't tried. I've only analyzed the problem from the standpoint of what's involved, not by trying it out. I still think you should try it in a database without a DAO reference.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: but without a DAO reference I couldn't refer to `DAO.Workspaces`, which seems to be what's causing the problem. Referring to `DBEngine.Workspaces` first makes subsequent references to `DAO.Workspaces` safe. Therefore both must be doing some sort of initialization, one right, one wrong.

Comment: My point is that if you remove the DAO reference, and the problem does not occur, you then know for certain that the problem is due to something in DAO. Thus, if you use the Application version of DBEngine for your workspaces reference, you shouldn't encounter the problem even when the DAO reference is in use. Given that Application.DBEngine does work without DAO, I'm assuming that Access talks directly to Jet. I assume DAO talks directly to Jet, too, but the issue seems to be that it does something different which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple workaround is to call CurrentDb prior to calling Workspaces for the first time:

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.Name
Debug.Print Workspaces.Count
Debug.Print CurrentDb.Name
```

I'll take a shot at demystifying what's going on, but this is just my theory.

The relevant bits of the Access help file are as follows (for CurrentDb):

> **Note**   In previous versions of
>   Microsoft Access, you may have used
>   the syntax
>   DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0) or
>   DBEngine(0)(0) to return a pointer to
>   the current database. In Microsoft
>   Access 2000, you should use the
>   CurrentDb method instead. **The
>   CurrentDb method creates another
>   instance of the current database,
>   while the DBEngine(0)(0) syntax refers
>   to the open copy of the current
>   database.** The CurrentDb method enables
>   you to create more than one variable
>   of type Database that refers to the
>   current database. Microsoft Access
>   still supports the DBEngine(0)(0)
>   syntax, but you should consider making
>   this modification to your code in
>   order to avoid possible conflicts in a
>   multiuser database.

And for the Workspaces collection:

> When you first refer to or use a
>   Workspace object, you **automatically
>   create the default workspace**,
>   DBEngine.Workspaces(0).

It would seem that by creating the default workspace prior to the first call to CurrentDb, you are somehow causing CurrentDb to forget how it should work.  It seems that instead of creating a new instance of the current database it just uses the one that's already lying around in the default Workspace.

Of course, this is all conjecture and I'm as curious as you to know the "real answer".

Comment: I actually found that workaround but it didn't get me any closer to understanding what is going on. (nor did reading the Help!) Another workaround I think is to never ever refer to the `Workspaces` collection.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you have a database open in the user interface, the workspace is already created.

Comment: I agree it makes no sense.  But it is the best (though admittedly weak) explanation I could come up with for why switching the order of the statements fixes the problem.

Comment: My point is that the explanation, that doing it a different way creates the workspace and doing it the other way does not is simply nonsensical. The cause clearly has to be something else, as the Jet workspace exists when you have a database open. Likely it's the library being used to return the workspace that has the initialization issues.